# Why do my various HTML tables all have varying widths?

Tags: html, css

I have been developing this template HTML file and I am encountering an issue.

Ideally, in all of the tables the left column **(0:00)** should always be the same size. And the 2 **name** columns should always be the same size. Then the **theme** column should take up the slack.

In my IE browser these columns are showing with different widths. What is my mistake?

```css
.cellBibleReading {
  padding-left: 3mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.cellTime {
  padding-left: 3mm;
  padding-right: 5mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: gray;
}
.cellName {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.floatRight {
  color: gray;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 2mm;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.tableDATE {
  margin-bottom: 2mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableDATE td {
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableTFGW {
  margin-bottom: 2mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableTFGW td {
  border: thin black solid;
}
.cellTFGW {
  padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textTFGW {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  background-color: #606a70;
  width: 90mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletTFGW {
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 1mm;
  color: #606a70;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.tableAYFM {
  margin-bottom: 2mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableAYFM td {
  border: thin black solid;
}
.cellAYFM {
  padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textAYFM {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  background-color: #c18626;
  width: 90mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletAYFM {
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 1mm;
  color: #c18626;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.cellClass {
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: gray;
}
.tableLAC {
  margin-bottom: 2mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableLAC td {
  border: thin black solid;
}
.cellLAC {
  padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textLAC {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  background-color: #961526;
  width: 90mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletLAC {
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 1mm;
  color: #961526;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textDuration {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textTheme {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongLabel {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongNumber {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textCongregation {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.textTitle {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.tableHeading {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5mm;
  border-bottom: thin black double;
}
.tableHeading td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableHeading">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="50%">
      <col width="50%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="textCongregation">CONGREGATION NAME</td>
    <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableDATE">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
      <div class="floatRight">
        Chairman:</div>
      DATE | WEEKLY BIBLE READING</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
      <div class="floatRight">
        Auxiliary Classroom Counselor:</div>
      &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Prayer:</div>
      <span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span><span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
      <span class="textSongNumber">XXX</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span><span class="textDuration">(3 
      min. or less)</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableDATE">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
      <div class="floatRight">
        Chairman:</div>
      DATE | WEEKLY BIBLE READING</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Prayer:</div>
      <span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span><span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
      <span class="textSongNumber">XXX</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span><span class="textDuration">(3 
      min. or less)</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTFGW">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2" style="width: 60%">
      <div class="textTFGW">
        TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Title</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(10 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Digging 
      for Spiritual gems</span>  <span class="textDuration">(8 min.)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student:</div>
      <span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Bible Reading</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTFGW">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="58%">
        <col width="20%">
          <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2" style="width: 60%">
      <div class="textTFGW">
        TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom</td>
    <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>
      <span class="textTheme">Title</span>  <span class="textDuration">(10 min.)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>
      <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual gems</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(8 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student:</div>
      <span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Bible Reading</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="3">
      <div class="textAYFM">
        APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Prepare 
      This Month's Presentations</span>  <span class="textDuration">(15 min.)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="58%">
        <col width="20%">
          <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2" style="width: 60%">
      <div class="textAYFM">
        APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom</td>
    <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Initial Call</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Return Visit</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Bible Study</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
      <div class="textAYFM">
        APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Initial Call</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Return Visit</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Bible Study</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableLAC">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellLAC" colspan="3">
      <div class="textLAC">
        LIVING AS CHRISTIANS</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
      <span class="textSongNumber">XXX</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textTheme">Title</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(00 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textTheme">Title</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(00 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Conductor/Reader:</div>
      <span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textTheme">Congregation 
      Bible Study</span>  <span class="textDuration">(30 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textTheme">Review/Preview/Announcements</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(3 min.)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Prayer:</div>
      <span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
      <span class="textSongNumber">XXX</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here are examples of what I am seeing in my browser:

**Left column:**

[image: Left column differs]

**Right column:**

[image: Right column differs]

Comment: No idea why you're seeing that, looks fine here https://jsfiddle.net/08pgeu7o/1/ **Chrome Version 49.0.2623.75 (64-bit)** - Personally, I would set percentage widths for each TD using css and classes - It may be that each browser/version treats TDs without defined widths differently (Not confirmed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to set fixed width to table you need to set `table-layout` to `fixed`

*first-cell migh be too short here*

You may just set a width to to the first col  and the 2 last ones, the second will fill up what is left, it will allow you to st px or em on first column and percentage on the 2 last ones

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  }
.cellBibleReading {
  padding-left: 3mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.cellTime {
  padding-left: 3mm;
  padding-right: 5mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: gray;
}
.cellName {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.floatRight {
  color: gray;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 2mm;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.tableDATE {
  margin-bottom: 2mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableDATE td {
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableTFGW {
  margin-bottom: 2mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableTFGW td {
  border: thin black solid;
}
.cellTFGW {
  padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textTFGW {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  background-color: #606a70;
  width: 90mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletTFGW {
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 1mm;
  color: #606a70;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.tableAYFM {
  margin-bottom: 2mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableAYFM td {
  border: thin black solid;
}
.cellAYFM {
  padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textAYFM {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  background-color: #c18626;
  width: 90mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletAYFM {
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 1mm;
  color: #c18626;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.cellClass {
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: gray;
}
.tableLAC {
  margin-bottom: 2mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.tableLAC td {
  border: thin black solid;
}
.cellLAC {
  padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textLAC {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  background-color: #961526;
  width: 90mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletLAC {
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 1mm;
  color: #961526;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textDuration {
  padding-left: 1mm;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textTheme {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongLabel {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongNumber {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textCongregation {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.textTitle {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.tableHeading {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5mm;
  border-bottom: thin black double;
}
.tableHeading td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableHeading">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="50%">
      <col width="50%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="textCongregation">CONGREGATION NAME</td>
    <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableDATE">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
      <div class="floatRight">
        Chairman:</div>
      DATE | WEEKLY BIBLE READING</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
      <div class="floatRight">
        Auxiliary Classroom Counselor:</div>
      &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Prayer:</div>
      <span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span><span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
      <span class="textSongNumber">XXX</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span><span class="textDuration">(3 
      min. or less)</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableDATE">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
      <div class="floatRight">
        Chairman:</div>
      DATE | WEEKLY BIBLE READING</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Prayer:</div>
      <span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span><span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
      <span class="textSongNumber">XXX</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span><span class="textDuration">(3 
      min. or less)</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTFGW">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2" style="width: 60%">
      <div class="textTFGW">
        TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Title</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(10 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Digging 
      for Spiritual gems</span>  <span class="textDuration">(8 min.)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student:</div>
      <span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Bible Reading</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTFGW">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="58%">
        <col width="20%">
          <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2" style="width: 60%">
      <div class="textTFGW">
        TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom</td>
    <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>
      <span class="textTheme">Title</span>  <span class="textDuration">(10 min.)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>
      <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual gems</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(8 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student:</div>
      <span class="bulletTFGW">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Bible Reading</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="3">
      <div class="textAYFM">
        APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Prepare 
      This Month's Presentations</span>  <span class="textDuration">(15 min.)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="58%">
        <col width="20%">
          <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2" style="width: 60%">
      <div class="textAYFM">
        APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom</td>
    <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Initial Call</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Return Visit</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Bible Study</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
      <div class="textAYFM">
        APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Initial Call</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Return Visit</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Student/Assistant:</div>
      <span class="bulletAYFM">&bull;</span>  <span class="textTheme">Bible Study</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableLAC">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2%">
      <col width="78%">
        <col width="20%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellLAC" colspan="3">
      <div class="textLAC">
        LIVING AS CHRISTIANS</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
      <span class="textSongNumber">XXX</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textTheme">Title</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(00 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td><span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textTheme">Title</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(00 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Conductor/Reader:</div>
      <span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textTheme">Congregation 
      Bible Study</span>  <span class="textDuration">(30 min.)</span> 
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name/Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textTheme">Review/Preview/Announcements</span>
      <span class="textDuration">(3 min.)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">0:00</td>
    <td>
      <div class="floatRight">
        Prayer:</div>
      <span class="bulletLAC">&bull;</span><span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
      <span class="textSongNumber">XXX</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tables by default adjust their column widths based on the contents of the table.  If you want the column sizes to match across multiple tables, your options are

- **Set explicit widths on the columns**.  This is what you're trying to do in your `colgroup`s, but (as you're seeing) content which overflows the width of a cel will still force that column to wider than specified.
- **Use `table-layout: fixed`**. This will force column sizes to be exactly as specified, but now content which doesn't fit the width of a cel will overflow the column boundaries, overlapping the next column.  This is rarely desirable behavior.
- **Don't use a table at all**. This would be a substantial rewrite of your code, but worth mentioning as a possibility; flexbox-based layouts can give you a lot more control than a table tag, often with simpler and more readable HTML. (My personal rule of thumb is if I use more than one `colspan` or more than zero `rowspan`s, it's time to switch over to flex instead).
- **Use a single table**.  For your current case this is probably the best approach -- it still takes advantage of the browser's ability to adjust the table to the content, while still keeping the column widths consistent throughout.

The below snippet shows a (very simplified) version of your code using a single table instead of multiple separate ones.  Note that you can include multiple `<thead>` and `<tbody>` in a single table, if that's semantically useful in your case.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
  border: 1px solid
}
td:eq(0) {
  width: 2%
}
td:eq(1) {
  width: 78%
}
td:eq(2) {
  width: 20%
}
.floatRight {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<table class="tableDATE">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="floatRight">Chairman:</div>
        DATE | WEEKLY BIBLE READING</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="floatRight">Auxiliary Classroom Counselor:</div>
        &nbsp;</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0:00</td>
      <td>
        <div class="floatRight">Prayer:</div>
        <span>&bull;</span><span>Song</span>
        <span>XXX</span>
      </td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0:00</td>
      <td colspan="2"><span>Opening Comments</span><span>(3 min. or less)</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="floatRight">Chairman:</div>
        DATE | WEEKLY BIBLE READING</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="floatRight">Auxiliary Classroom Counselor:</div>
        &nbsp;</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0:00</td>
      <td>
        <div class="floatRight">Prayer:</div>
        <span>&bull;</span><span>Song</span>
        <span>XXX</span>
      </td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0:00</td>
      <td colspan="2"><span>Opening Comments</span><span>(3 min. or less)</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```